# myLabel display the wrong name (UIDatePicker)

Tags: swift, label, uidatepicker

I have a problem, my label displays the wrong month name after selected from DatePicker.

[img app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VutlF.png)

Code:

```
    let myDatePicker: UIDatePicker = {
    let pv = UIDatePicker()
    pv.datePickerMode = .date
    pv.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")
    pv.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
    return pv
}()

@objc func datePickerValueChanged(datePicker: UIDatePicker) {

    let format = "dd MMM, yyyy"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = format

    let dateValue = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)

    myLabel.text = dateValue
}

let myLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    return label
}()
```

P.S I have an additional question how to set the language of months in DatePicker automatically with regional settings?

I tried (inside myDatePicker) : `pv.locale = .current`

Comment: `dateFormatter.locale = datePicker.locale`. DateFormatter also have locale to be set. Also a "calendar" object if you want.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I updated my code again. As I understand in func datePickerValueChanged , I don't know exactly where?

Comment: Yes, in your `datePickerValueChanged`, put this after initializing the `DateFormatter` and *before* formatting the string `dateFormatter.string(from: dataPicker.date)`

Comment: It works great. And you know how to automatically get the correct month names retrieved from the Phone's regional settings? I tried pv.locale = Locale.current

Comment: Use `Locale.autoupdatingCurrent` instead of a definite hard-coded locale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question:

You need to "localize" your dateFormatter, using

```
dateFormatter.locale = datePicker.locale
```

in your `datePickerValueChanged`

Second question:

You want to retrieve the correct month names as retrieved from the iPhone settings

Use `Locale.autoupdatingCurrent` instead of `Locale(identifier: "de_DE")`
. This gets the user preferred current locale, automatically up-to-date.

Comment: Unfortunately, "Locale.autoupdatingCurrent" doesn't work, it tests on a physical device, but I still have month names in English. I've also checked breakpoint on: pv.locale = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent " and get this formula: 
Optional<Locale>, some: en_DE (current), - identifier : "en_DE", kind : "current"

Comment: I think you set your iPhone language to English, while your Region is Germany. Try setting iPhone language to Deutsch.

Comment: It works. I had the iPhone language set to Deutsch and the region to Germany. And the problem was that "Prefered language order" was German and English, it was enough to remove English. Thank you very much for help